# how to maintain status of failed file

Tags: java

I am new in java .I am developing an app in java to transfer a large number of files to server.The requirement is to check the status of failed file and store somewhere and transfer those files later.The application should be maintain a daemon process.

Thanks and Regard

sanjeet

Comment: *...and where is the code?*

Comment: And what's your concrete question?

Comment: This site is to help you fix _your_ code, not write your application for you.  If you have a specific problem please post it, but "I'm writing something" isn't a question.

Answer (score 0):

The better option for large number of files transfer is to use ftp protocol. For that you need an ftp server. And, using [org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html) you may upload files in to the server (and also various file management).

The `storeFile(String, InputStream)` method of `org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient` can give the file upload status, i.e. if the file is uploaded successfully it will return true otherwise false.

Please refer [this link for a sample program](http://www.journaldev.com/661/java-ftp-upload-example-using-apache-commons-net-api).